# how to map value from multiple variance dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

```
mapdict = {('a', 'b', 'c'): 1, ('d', 'e', 'f'): 2}
dsf = ['b','e']
dsf = pd.Series(dsf)
dsf.map(mapdict)
```

But, map result is `NaN`. I expected that [1,2] as result from `mapdict`.
Anyone know how to map value from multiple variance in one dictionary ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need unpack the keys of `mapdict`

```py
mapdict = {k: v for ks, v in mapdict.items() for k in ks}
out = dsf.map(mapdict)
```

```
print(mapdict)

{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 2, 'f': 2}


print(out)

0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```